# Config flat-pickr date and time in vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm working on flat-pickr. And now to the config part. I have two fields: `start date` and `end date`. I want when I select the time at `start date` it defaults to 12h AM. And choose the time at the `end date`, it defaults to 12h PM

[image]

```
// start date
<flat-pickr
     id="campaign-startdate"
     v-model="model.startdate"
     class="form-control"
     :config="formatStartDate"
/>
// end date
<flat-pickr
     id="campaign-enddate"
     v-model="model.endDate"
     class="form-control"
     :config="formatEndDate"
/>

data() {
  return: {
    model:{
      startDate: null,
      endDate: null,
    },
    formatStartDate: {
        enableTime: true,
        dateFormat: 'd-m-Y H:i'
    },
    formatEndDate: {
      enableTime: true,
      dateFormat: 'd-m-Y H:i'
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set in configuration default time hours and minute for each picker.

```
 configStartDate: {
    altFormat: "F j, Y",
    altInput: true,
    enableTime: true,
    defaultHour:0,
    
  },
  configEndDate:{
   altFormat: "F j, Y",
    altInput: true,
    enableTime: true,
    defaultHour:12,
    
  }
```

Set **defaultHour:0** for startdate and set **defaultHour:12** for enddate

Refer to link for demo [flatpickr](https://jsfiddle.net/ketanmokariya/j1x7kwuo/2/)